# Calculate Total in a Given Row

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am developing a system where i need this:

- I have various rows on one table, and one of them is Total
- I want the script that can add the total of all the fields in the Total column.
- I will then add the session user so that it only calculates all total fields in that column for that particular person.

You can get me the query: Example the search query for 30 days is this

```
$query="SELECT * 
          FROM clientdata 
         WHERE ADDTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() 
           AND member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] . "'";
```

So you can also add the session details on the code you post below

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it right but I think you want to do this

```
select sum(total) WHERE ADDTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() AND member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

use MySQLs [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(total), * FROM clientdata WHERE ADDTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() AND member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] . "'";
```

only use the `, *` bit of the query if you want/need more data out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, and you didn't provide your table layout, but when you say "total of all fields in Total column", does that mean you have a table that looks like:

```
id | field1 | field2 | field3 | ... | Total | UserID
```

and you want the `Total` column to equal `field1 + field2 + field3 + ...`? Or do you have some thing like:

```
id | Type     | Value | UserID
1  | 'field1' |  ...  |  ..
2  | 'field2' |  ...  |  ..
3  | 'field3' |  ...  |  ..
4  | 'Total'  |  ...  |  ..
```

For the first one, the query is simple:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(field1 + field2 + field3 + ...) AS Total
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID
```

for the second:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Value) AS Total
FROM table
GROUP BY 'UserID', 'Type'
WHERE ('Field' <> 'Total')
```

... or maybe I'm totally misreading your question.